# Why does clear hashmap method clears added map in array list

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to reuse same HashMap like in example bellow to populate list. First I put some values in the map, add map to the list and then clear map in order to put again new values and add second set of values in the list and so on...

But, it seems that clear() method also delete values previously added in the list and if I don't use clear() method every set of values previously added in the list is overwritten with new set of values so that in the end in this particular example i will have 4 identical value sets in the list.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
    List<HashMap<String, String>>dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(Answer.ID, "0");
    map.put(Answer.IMAGE, "color_icon_awesome");
    map.put(Answer.TITLE, firstOption);
    dataList.add(map);
    map.clear();             

    map.put(Answer.ID, "1");
    map.put(Answer.IMAGE, "color_icon_awesome");
    map.put(Answer.TITLE, secondOption);
    dataList.add(map);
    map.clear();

    map.put(Answer.ID, "2");
    map.put(Answer.IMAGE, "color_icon_awesome");
    map.put(Answer.TITLE, thirdOption);
    dataList.add(map);
    map.clear();

    map.put(Answer.ID, "3");
    map.put(Answer.IMAGE, "color_icon_awesome");
    map.put(Answer.TITLE, fourthOption);
    dataList.add(map);
    map.clear();
```

Comment: You seem to be creating a list of single-entry maps. This is a very unusual data structure. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps there is a more appropriate (and easier-to-use) data structure you can use instead.

Comment: You should also look into using an `EnumMap`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dataList.add(map)` will put a reference to `map` in the list, so it's not a copy. When you then do `map.clear()` afterwards, it erases the content of the map in the list too, because it is the very same object. Do `dataList.add(map.clone())` instead or (preferably) do `map = new HashMap<>();` afterwards.

```
map.put(Answer.ID, "0");
map.put(Answer.IMAGE, "color_icon_awesome");
map.put(Answer.TITLE, firstOption);
dataList.add(map);
map = new HashMap<>();
```

**Sidenote:** Your code looks like you could use an object instead of the map:

```
class AnswerObject {

  private String id;
  private String image;
  private String title;

  public AnswerObject(String id, String image, String title) {
      this.id = id;
      this.image = image;
      this.title = title;
  }

  // some getters and setters and some other usefull code

}
```

This should make your code nicer and more readable

```
List<AnswerObject> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.add(new AnswerObject("0", "color_icon_awesome", firstOption));
dataList.add(new AnswerObject("1", "color_icon_awesome", secondOption));
dataList.add(new AnswerObject("2", "color_icon_awesome", thirdOption));
dataList.add(new AnswerObject("3", "color_icon_awesome", fourthOption));
```

But feel free to ignore that ;-)

Comment: Actually great idea using object. I do have it, but in all the rush I just followed an old example, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same map to your list. Are you trying to have a list of Strings that come from your map or list of Maps? If you trying to have a list of maps then you need to create a new map each time. Once you put a map into list and modify the contents of the map you are modifying the same map that you added into your list. Just change your code in your add method and instead of `dataList.add(map);` do `dataList.add(new HashMap(map));` this will solve your problem